# Sails 0.10 ModelIdentity.subscribe or .watch and for publishCreate()?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm studying the [SailsCasts](http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/) and I'm working on **SailsJS beta version 0.10**.

Everything works except when in **0.9.7**, I use this:

```
//subscribe this socket to the User model classroom
User.subscribe(req.socket);

// subscribe this socket to the user instance rooms
User.subscribe(req.socket, users);
```

- How to do this for 0.10?

Especially, the subscribe for `publishUpdate` and `publishDestroy` works fine.

For `publishCreate`, I need `'User.subscribe(req.socket)'` and I have in console the warning:

```
debug: Deprecated: Model.subscribe(socket, null, ...)
debug: (see http://links.sailsjs.org/docs/config/pubsub)
debug: Please use instance rooms instead (or raw sails.sockets.*() methods.)
```

And then:

- What are the differences between `'model.watch()'` and `'model.subscribe()'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Question 1

I'd prefer to comment (lack rep...), but have you given [the docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/tree/0.10/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub) a good read?

You can't call .subscribe like `User.subscribe(req.socket)`. It requires a second param `records`. So your `User.subscribe(req.socket, users);` should work if users is a list of user model instances.

### Question 2

I'm no expert (at all...) with node or sails, but [the docs - watch](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.10/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/watch.md) claim`model.watch()` subscribes clients to publishCreate events for the model instances. I see no mention of publishUpdate,publishDestory, etc. I think it only watches creation events.  `.subscribe()` takes a list of models (or a model) and subscribes the client to publishAdd, publishDestroy, publishRemove, publishUpdate events (by default) for that list of model instances. You can also specify what contexts you want to subscribe to.

So, it seems you actually want to use `User.watch(req.socket)` instead of `.subscribe()` if you only want to send the socket publishCreate events. If you need all of them, use something like `User.subscribe(req.socket,users,[create,update,destroy,])`.
If you want to be cool, you can set the `autosubscribe` property to contain the list of the contexts you care about and just use `User.subscribe(req.socket,users)` [the docs - context](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.10/reference/websockets/resourceful-pubsub/subscribe.md#context).

Cheers

Comment: both doc links you provide are now dead (404). You may want to update your post accordingly

Answer (score 1):

In order to subscribe to a model:

```
subscribe: function(req, res) {
    Model.find().exec(function(err, records) {
        YourModel.subscribe(req.socket, records);
        YourModel.watch(req);
    });
}
```

This way, you get a message each time a record is created, destroyed or updated.